# get the max(date) value and join 2 tables

Tags: sql

Have 2 tables,
Table 1 has username, created (timestamp), dim
Table 2 has username, dob

Need to join table and get the dim from table 1 with the max(created) for each username.
[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current query attempt. And add a tag for the dbms you're using. I.e. [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t2.username, t1.created, t1.dim,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.username
                              ORDER BY t1.created DESC) rn
    FROM Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.username = t1.username
)

SELECT username, created, dim
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```